how to check if the path from where the script is started stored on a hdd or ssd drive?
how to check if the path from where the script is started stored on a hdd or ssd drive?
i have read that cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational show 0 for ssd and 1 for hdd.
if [ "$(</sys/block/sda/queue/rotational)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "SSD"
else
    echo "HDD"
fi

but how can this combined with . or $PWD for checking?

What if the current working directory is on a RAID array with both SSD and HDD or a zfs dataset in a pool with HDDs and SSDs as l2arc and/or slog? Or a fuse FS mounting a remote webdav server (with storage there backed by SSDs or HDDs)

@StéphaneChazelas or LVM.

This sounds like an XY problem to me. It’s vanishingly unlikely that a shell script will legitimately have to care about this, and while it may be of pedagogical interest it’s also something that is far far more complex than the question makes it out to be (there are literally dozens of layers that could be between userspace and the actual storage device that would affect things just as much as the underlying device type).

What I would do:
. is the current directory.
#!/bin/bash

dev=$(df -P . | awk 'NR==2 {print $1;exit}')
res=$(lsblk -n -o ROTA $dev)
if ((res == 0)); then
    printf '%s\n' 'SSD'
else
    printf '%s\n' 'Not SSD'
fi

Notes & limitations
lsblk is typically already installed on GNU/Linux OSes. This is not the case on FreeBSD by example.
Moreover, /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational is Linux specific.
See Stéphane Chazelas's comment about special cases.

# Get the canonical absolute path to the current working directory
#
# Note that in most cases, if you care about some physical property of the 
# current working directory, you need to get the path this way to ensure 
# consistency.
dir="$(pwd -P)"

# Use that to get the path under `/dev` for the device
dev="$(df -P "${dir}" | awk 'NR==2 {print $1;exit}')"

if [ -b "${dev}" ]; then
    # Use that to then construct the path under `/sys/block` for the device
    # The `readlink` invocation is needed here because `/sys/block` only has 
    # entries for actual devices, and the path we found above may have symlinks
    sys_path="/sys/block/$(basename "$(readlink "${dev}")")"

    if [ -r "${sys_path}/queue/rotational" ]; then
        if [ "$(cat "${sys_path}/queue/rotational")" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Device is non-rotational"
        else
            echo "Device is rotational"
        fi
    else
        echo "Device type cannot be determined"
    fi
else
    echo "Filesystem is not backed by a block device"
fi

The above code is largely POSIX compliant (intentionally, because not all Linux systems use Bash). Everything up to actually checking the path under /sys should in fact work on pretty much any Linux system (even those using Busybox or Toybox, which are a recurring source of problems for shell scripting), any BSD system, and possibly other platforms as well.
However, there are a couple of major limitations to this:

/sys is a Linux thing, so the actual check will not work on anything other than a Linux system.
/sys may be locked down and not allow access by arbitrary users. This is common on highly secured systems. This is the reason for the second if condition that checks if the queue/rotational file exists and is readable.
A filesystem may not have an associated block device. Network filesystems and tmpfs are the classic examples of this, but there are others. This is the reason for the outermost if condition.
Just because a block device is rotational does not mean it’s a hard drive. Optical drives (such as CD-ROM drives) are also rotational, as are floppy drives, Zip drives, magneto-optical drives, and probably some other types that I’m not aware of.
Just because a block device is non-rotational does not mean it’s an SSD. Ramdisks are also non-rotational, as are NBD devices, ZRAM devices, loop devices (usually), ZFS zvols, paravirtualized block devices (such as VirtIO block devices), SD cards, eMMC storage, and a whole long list of other things you’re even less likely to encounter than any of those.
Device mapper devices, MD arrays, and possibly other types of devices, may mix rotational and non-rotational storage in the underlying layers, and as a result it’s not possible to infer much of anything from the rotational status of these device types (though DM and MD devices will actually report rotational status correctly if all of the lower-level devices comprising the higher-level device are rotational or non-rotational).


This is why you should wait 24 hours before accepting an answer.
